Woo Commerce dropdown menu does not display items
WooCommerce dropdown menu does not display items
currently i have to tipe it out to find what im looking for. Before you clocked the drop down menu and all the categories and subcategories were neatly displayed.
adding pictures this is what im triing to fix
this is what its suposed to look like
I dont know what to try
